# What is the C++ idiom to replace snprintf(3)?

Tags: c++

I have some C++ code which needs to generate an error message when parsing a certain file header fails. In this case, I need to ensure that a certain 4 byte field in the header is "OggS", and if it is not, return an error message like "invalid capture_pattern: 'FooB'; expecting 'OggS'". My code looks something like this:

```
const string OggPage::parseHeader(void) {
  read(fd, capture_pattern, sizeof(capture_pattern)); // error handling omitted
  if (strncmp(capture_pattern, CAPTURE_PATTERN, sizeof(capture_pattern)) != 0) {
    char err[256];
    snprintf(err, sizeof(err), "Failed to read %d bytes from file descriptor %d: %s\n", sizeof(capture_pattern), fd, err);
    return err;
  }

  return "Everything was A-OK!";
}
```

What is the standard C++ idiom for building a string from other datatypes? I'm not wedded to the `printf(3)`-style format here, so feel free to suggest anything that works.

Comment: Aside note: You forgot a `)` in `sizeof(capture_pattern)`.

Comment: Just a note... remove this 'just a note' note since you accepted an answer involving <iostream>

Comment: @tea Just a note... I removed the 'just a note' note in response to your 'just a note' comment. ;-P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stringstream` or `ostringstream`from C++ Standard library. If further stream will not be used to read values from it (e.g. it's `istream` part won't be used) `ostringstream` is more suitable.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 std::stringstream str_stream;
 int number = 5;

 str_stream << " String with number " << number << std::endl;;

 std::string str = str_stream.str();
 std::cout << str; 
}
```

Comment: That is C++ Standard Library, not STL.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Thanks for correction. Answer has been corrected.

Comment: Why `std::stringstream`, and not `std::ostringstream`?

Comment: @James Kanze: Both of them can be used in this situation, but in the absence of input from stream ostringstream can be more suitable, you right. I will note this in the answer.

Comment: @beduin As a general rule, I would avoid bidirectional streams unless I need the bidirectionality.  Although I picked on you (your answer showed up first on my machine), all of the responses used `stringstream`, rather than `ostringstream`.  There's no point in the extra complexity unless you need it.

Comment: Thanks! Of course, in entering the question, I completely forgot which problem I was trying to solve! If you're up for a bit more of a challenge: [How to deal with unterminated character arrays when building C++ strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853855/how-to-deal-with-unterminated-character-arrays-when-building-c-strings)

Answer (score 1):

C++ way of doing this is [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/).

```
std::stringstream err;
err << "Failed to read " << sizeof(capture_pattern)
                         << " bytes from fd " << fd << std::endl;
return err.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string functions from `cstring` is definitely fine for reading. They're fast, convenient and not verbose.

For building your error messages, you can use `stringstream`, operators related to the `string` class, [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/format/) or, as you put it, `snprintf`.

You have also `boost::lexical_cast` for simple things:

```
string message = "Failed to read " + lexical_cast<string>(n) +
   " bytes from the descriptor " + lexical_cast<string>(fd) + ".";
```

I recommend having a look at [this Gotw](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm) for a sane point of view.

I'd recommend `boost::format` if you have a lot of formatting to do. Use `lexical_cast` for simple isolated things, and use `stringstream` if you have requirements which makes you need them (eg. custom `operator<<`, cannot use `boost`, etc).

To be honest, `snprintf` is really fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Just as a note, please don't suggest  replacements for the actual reading--there is a reason that I want to use the C standard library for I/O here. :)

You can't really ask for "idiomatic" ways to do something in C++, and then say "but I want to stick to the C standard library...

Anyway, you have three options. I don't believe any of them is *idiomatic* (because that would imply some kind of consensus about this being the *best* way):

- stick with the C APIs you're already using
- Use the the C++ `std::stringstream`, which is part the iostreams section of the standard library
- use Boost.Format

The latter has the downside that it relies on a third-party library, but the advantage that it gives you `printf`-like syntax, in a typesafe and extensible manner, which interoperates cleanly with C++ streams.

Comment: `strncmp` is definitely fine, and "idiomatic": find a better way to do this to see what I mean.

Comment: Eh? How can a C string compare function be an idiomatic solution for string formatting in C++?

Comment: @Alexandre but it doesn't solve the problem the OP asked for. How can a solution be idiomatic if it solves the wrong problem?

Comment: @jalf: I was asking for a very specific C++ idiomatic solution, and I didn't want people to get distracted by telling me about `<iostream>` for reading data. :)

Comment: @Josh: ah, fair enough. `stringstream`, which is one of the "almost-idiomatic" options is usually considered part of the iostream library, so I wasn't sure if you meant that you didn't want to use that either.

Answer (score 0):

You create a stringstream, write what you want using the '<<' operator and then get the string out of stream with the member function .str().

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

stringstream err;
err << "Failed to read " << sizeof(capture_pattern) << " bytes from file descriptor: " << fd << endl;
string outstr = err.str();
```