# How to deal with unterminated character arrays when building C++ strings?

Tags: c++

As noted in [What is the C++ idiom to replace snprintf(3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847480/what-is-the-c-idiom-to-replace-snprintf3), I'm parsing a file header and building an error message if a certain four-byte field in the header is corrupt. This code sums up what I'm trying to do:

```
const std::string parseCapturePattern(const int fd) { // fd is the descriptor of the ogg file
  const char CAPTURE_PATTERN[4] = {'O', 'g', 'g', 'S'};
  char capture_pattern[4];

  read(fd, capture_pattern, sizeof(capture_pattern)); // error handling omitted
  if (strncmp(capture_pattern, CAPTURE_PATTERN, sizeof(capture_pattern)) != 0) {
    std::ostringstream err;
    /*** This won't actually work ***/
    err_msg << "Invalid capture pattern: '" << capture_pattern << "'; expecting '"
        << CAPTURE_PATTERN << "'";
    /*** This won't actually work ***/

    return err.str();
  }
}
```

This will not work because `capture_pattern` and `CAPTURE_PATTERN` are not NULL-terminated character arrays. What does work is this:

```
    err_msg << "Invalid capture pattern: '" << capture_pattern[0] << capture_pattern[1] 
        << capture_pattern[2] << capture_pattern[3] << "'; expecting '"
        << CAPTURE_PATTERN[0] << CAPTURE_PATTERN[1] << CAPTURE_PATTERN[2]
        << CAPTURE_PATTERN[3] << "'";
```

That, of course, is almost indescribably hideous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string(capture_pattern, capture_pattern+4)` will construct a string from the 4 first characters of `capture_pattern`.

Comment: Perfect! If C++ is this easy, who needs Ruby? ;)

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas:

Either use a null terminated string, and use a string find function:
const char CAPTURE_PATTERN[] = "OggS";

You could then use strstr on a null terminated string.  This is of course a problem if you don't want to add a null character on the end, but could be beneficial if you wanted to search a large chunk of data at once with strstr()

The other idea would be to use memcmp().  Similar to string comparison, but works directly on what you pass it.  You won't need null termination, and can still initialize your string with const char CAPTURE_PATTERN[] = "OggS";

Comment: Good ideas, but I wanted to do it in idiomatic C++ if possible--using the C standard library in C++ is sometimes necessary, but I think one should use the facilities that an object-oriented language (or standard library, in this case) provides whenever possible. If nothing else, it makes unit testing easier. :)